# PHP not posting onto mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

This code should check for existing usernames and if there isn't one, it should create a new one. No matter what it won't add. Additionally, as you can see in the code it only echoes 'here' and doesn't echo 'not here'.

```
<?php 

$password = "hey";
$username = "hi";
require "conn.php";
//$password = $_POST["password"];
//$username = $_POST["username"];

echo 'here';
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM UserData WHERE username ='$username' ", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);
echo 'not here';
if ($result) { 

    if($result->num_rows === 0)
    {

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO UserData (username,password) VALUES (:username,:password)");
        $params = array(
            ':username' => $username,
            ':password' => $password
        );
        $stmt->execute($params);
    }

}
?>
```

This is the connection code:

```
    <?php 
    //$db_name = "xxx";
    //$mysql_username = "xxx";
    //$mysql_password = "xxx";
    //$server_name = "xxx";
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli("xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx");
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    echo "Connected successfully";

    ?>
```

Changes:

```
<?php 
require "conn.php";
echo "debug 1";
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM UserData WHERE username = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', /*$_POST["username"]*/ $username );
$username = 'hi'; 
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();

echo "debug 2";
if ($stmt->num_rows == 0){ // username not taken
  echo "debug 3";
  $stmt2 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO UserData (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)");
  $password =(/*$_POST["password"]*/ "hey");
  $username =(/* $_POST["username"]*/ "hi");  
  $stmt2->bind_param('s',$username);
  $stmt2->bind_param('s',$password);
  $stmt2->execute();
  if ($stmt2->affected_rows == 1){
    echo 'Insert was successful.';

  }else{ echo 'Insert failed.';
   var_dump($stmt2);
  }
}else{ echo 'That username exists already.';}

?>
```

This code gets through all of the debugs but for some reason, it is still not inserting.

Comment: How/where is `$mysqli` set?  (used after the 'here' output)

Comment: It is in the conn.php file

Comment: Can you show the contents of that file?  Set the user and pass text info. to something arbitrary, if needed. I'm thinking that `$mysqli` should be replaced by `$conn`, but I don't really know without more info.

Comment: So `$mysqli` is not set to anything, but `$conn` is set by `new mysqli( ... )`. So, trying replacing the the `$mysqli` with `$conn` as mentioned in my last comment for the query after the `'here'` output. Which should look like: `$result = $conn->query("SELECT ... ");`

Comment: like so.... $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM UserData WHERE username ='$username' ", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);

Comment: Yes, like that.

Comment: It does print here and not here but it doesn't insert anything

Comment: Do a `var_dump($result);` after the `'not here'` and see what you get. If it's false, then you are not getting to the insert statement area. If it's not false, then you might need to print the num_rows before the other condition. If you have one row, then you still won't get to the insert.

Comment: Check your query is it fire or not...

Comment: First of all, why will I not get to the insert if I have one row? Second, What do you mean by is it fire or not.

Comment: I have debugged that the code is getting to the inserting part but not inserting.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line 
`$result = **$mysqli->**query("SELECT * FROM UserData WHERE username ='$username' ", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);`
 with following 
`$result = **$conn->**query("SELECT * FROM UserData WHERE username ='$username' ", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);`

Answer (score 0):

The mysqli and PDO interfaces must not be mixed. Here the database connection and the SELECT query are both using the mysqli interface. But the second INSERT query is attempting to use the PDO interface, as evidenced by the use of named placeholders, and also the passing of a data array directly to execute(). The latter two features are not supported by mysqli, hence the code fails at the second query. Also, note that the second query is using prepared statements, while the first one is not. Again, different approaches should not be mixed together.

Also it appears that passwords are being stored as plain text, with no security. The proper approach is to use the password_hash function.
Just ensure that the database field has enough width (say 80-120 characters or more) to handle the current bcrypt hash, plus allow some more for future changes.

Staying with the mysqli interface (and with password_hash), the code could go something like this:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM UserData WHERE username = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST["username"]);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
if ($stmt->num_rows == 0){ // username not taken
  $stmt2 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO UserData (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)");
  $password = password_hash($_POST["password"], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
  $stmt2->bind_param('s', $_POST["username"]);
  $stmt2->bind_param('s', $password);
  $stmt2->execute();
  if ($stmt2->affected_rows == 1)
    echo 'Insert was successful.';    
  else echo 'Insert failed.';
}
else echo 'That username exists already.';
```

Note that the above approach would not be suitable for a high-traffic site, where there is a chance condition of another user trying to INSERT the same username, during the brief interval of time between the SELECT and INSERT database queries. That would require a different approach, like ensuring the subject database field is set to UNIQUE (which is good practice anyway), and then testing for violation of that UNIQUE field upon attempted duplicate insertion.

Assuming database and INSERT permissions are all set up OK and it is still not inserting, try enhancing the error-reporting.

Ensure the following are at the top of the page:

```
ini_set('display_errors', true); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

And put the following before the first query:

```
$driver = new mysqli_driver();
$driver->report_mode = MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL;
```

Then try again.